# Can't understand how the do while loop in the end is working

Tags: c, do-while

I am trying but just can't figure out how the last do-while loop in the program is working.
It is supposed to print the characters of the file from the end to the first position and terminate when it crosses the bounds of the file.
The code i am showing is working, but i am not getting how.
The while condition is what i can't seem to understand, why the not symbol ! is used with the condition in while.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        long n, k;
        char c;
        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen("RANDOM", "w");
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
                putc(c, fp);
        }
        n = ftell(fp);
        printf("\nNo. of characters entered by the user is : %ld\n", n);
        fclose(fp);
        fp = fopen("RANDOM", "r");
        k = 0L;
        while (feof(fp) == 0) {
                fseek(fp, k, 0);
                n = ftell(fp);
                c = getc(fp);
                printf("The character at %ld position is %c\n", n, c);
                k += 5L;
        }
        fseek(fp, -1L, 2);
        do {
                printf("%c", getc(fp));
        } while(!fseek(fp, -2L, 1));
        putchar('\n');
}
```

This code works fine, just can't understand why, not "!" of the condition in the last while is used because i thought of using the same condition but without the not part.

Comment: "This code works fine" and `while (feof(fp) == 0) { ...   c = getc(fp); 
                printf("... is %c\n", c);` is suspect as that prints a character with the value of `(unsigned char) EOF`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[fseek](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/) returns `0` on successful and a non-zero value on unsuccessful.

> Return Value

```
If successful, the function returns zero.
Otherwise, it returns non-zero value.
```

So when it is successful it will return `0` and you would want to continue when it does. Hence the `not`

Answer (score 1):

C does not have a separate type family for boolean values.  It uses integers -- 0 means `false`, and anything else means `true`.  The `_Bool` type introduced in C99 is an integer type that can represent these values, and other integer types can be used freely to represent boolean values.  The logical operator `!` just swaps these; `!x` is equivalent to `(x == 0) ? 1 : 0`, which is itself equivalent to just `(x == 0)`.

Like many C functions `fseek()`'s return value indicates its success or failure.  It is common that negative values represent failure, and non-negative ones success; details vary a bit, and `fseek()` specifically uses `0` for success and `-1` for failure.

The predicate of the `while` loop in question ...

```
while(!fseek(fp, -2L, 1))
```

... can thus be interpreted as "call `fseek(fp, -2L, 1)` and perform another iteration if it succeeds, as indicated by returning 0".  The call attempts to move backward past the character just read (and printed), and onward past one further character, with the effect, if it succeeds, that the next character read will be the one immediately preceding the previous character read in the file.

Comment: "C does not have a separate boolean data type."  Disagree since C99, there is `_Bool` which the spec calls a _boolean type_, an object large enough to store the values 0 and 1.

Comment: Ok, @chux, I hope my revised language is now satisfactorily precise.

Comment: The boolean, `_Bool` issue is tangential and it does not come into play here.  `while (expression )` simple compares the _expression_ against 0.

Comment: And the expression in question is one involving the *logical negation* operator, @chux, which is at least inspired by boolean logic.  Moreover, the reason and or meaning of applying that operator to the return value of `fseek()`, an `int`, is one of the OP's express points of confusion.  This is where the boolean issue is important (not `_Bool` in particular, I agree, but *you* brought that up).